# Manifest Merger Failed - accessing google maps v2 permissions

Tags: java, android, google-maps, manifest

**Hello, I am building an app through stackskills lollipop tutorial in android studio.  I am following tutorial exactly and have recieved this error, I can't figure out what is wrong here please take a look at my manifest**  I appreciate your HELP!

**HERE IS ERROR**

```
Error:(24, 13) Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#com.google.android.gms.version@value value=(730) from AndroidManifest.xml:24:13
    is also present at com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.3.0:23:13 value=(@integer/google_play_services_version)
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:23:9 to override
```

**HERE IS MY MANIFEST**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.hailey.parse" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        </activity>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="730"/>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="I am ommiting the key here but it is in the code correctly"/>
    </application>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 10):

As per [this Google+ post](https://plus.google.com/+IanLake/posts/8ewDRqGUFyp), Google Play services 7.0 and higher automatically includes the `<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"` line for you - you can leave this out of your Manifest entirely.

Comment: If this helped answer your question, please make sure to accept the answer to remove it from the unanswered queue. Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 2):

its not needed to declare in manifest

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="730"/>
```

this one is remove then its work proper way.
Thanks Regards

Answer (score 0):

your Problem is in the following line

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="730"/>
```

Try to replace "730" with "@integer/google_play_services_version"

I think this can help you.